# Removing index.php from second position only using htaccess

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

how can i remove index.php only at second position using .htaccess ??

i tried to do this using following code :

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*index\.php [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/system/.* [NC]
RewriteRule (.*?)index\.php/*(.*) /$1$2 [R=301,NE,L]


RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*index [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/system/.* [NC]
RewriteRule (.*?)index /$1$2 [R=301,NE,L]
```

and it is working perfectly. But in my admin panel there are some index keyword is used at 3rd-4th position so this script also removing that index key word by which my panel links are not working correctly.

Can any one tell me the solution to remove index and index.php keyword only at second position in URL. only from www.example.com/index.php and www.example.com/index  not from www.example.com/folder1/folder2/index/page/ or www.example.com/folder1/folder2/folder3/index/page/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace both your rules with this:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s+/index [NC]
RewriteRule ^index(?:\.php)?(?:/(.*))?$ /$1 [L,R=301,NC,NE]
```

Comment: thanks anubhava for ur quick reply. i did as u say but using this script my some links are working but some are not and also it sowing www.example.com/index.php in url whenever its it.

Comment: sir still it removing each index keyword in the url. I need to remove index only at second position it redirecting this url www.example.com/admin/user/index/status/1 to  www.example.com/admin/user/ this url which i don't want.

Comment: Test in a new browser and make sure you don't have any other rule in any of the htaccess files to remove index.

Comment: RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s+/index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^index\.php?(?:/(.*))?$ /$1 [L,R=301,NC,NE]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/images/branding.jpg
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule !\.(js|ico|gif|jpg|png|css)$ index.php

Comment: Don't post code in comments. Edit your question and post it there.

Comment: great it is working in other browser in chrome thanks thanks alot sir...   but this www.example.com/index url is not redirecting to www.example.com.

Comment: sir can you please give me your email address..??

Comment: Sir your email address is not working. given error "Google tried to deliver your message, but it was rejected by the server for the recipient domain aol.com"

Comment: I mis-typed from mobile. It is `anubhava[at]aol[dot]com`